# Where is the ssh URL for repos in github these days?

Tags: github, git-clone, github-cli

I just went into a github repo to get the ssh URL for it and all I see is the https one and the instructions to clone with github-cli. I know I can probably make up the ssh-one from the https one but why is the ssh one missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the middle option, you need to login to see it. Otherwise, it only shows `HTTPS` and `Github CLI`.

[image]

---

Comment: Hmm... interesting.... I only see 2 options.... is it because  it's a non-logged-in tab?

Comment: Yeah.... I think that's it. Just tried in a logged window and the tab is there. Ok. Great to know.

Comment: @eftshift0 wow, why would they lock that feature for anonymous users.

Comment: Well.... if you are using ssh it means you are using the keys that you have already set up so not really anonymous.... still a pain. Would you mind adding that to your answer? I added an answer of my own but I think yours is enough, with that little detail added.

Comment: Note that when the web browser zoom is high (more than 150%), the code button may not be visible...